Change language using next intl
"use client";

import React, { useTransition } from "react";
import style from "@/app/components/header/header.module.scss";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useLocale } from "next-intl";

const LocalSwitcher = () => {
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const router = useRouter();
  const localActive = useLocale();

  const onSelectChange = (e) => {
    const nextLocale = e.target.value;
    startTransition(() => {
      router.replace(`${nextLocale}`);
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select className={style.languageSelection} onChange={onSelectChange} defaultValue={localActive} disabled={isPending}>
        <option value="az">AZ</option>
        <option value="en">EN</option>
        <option value="ru">RU</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LocalSwitcher

So I have used this switcher in the header section. When I change the language using that select option, the url changes, the content changes, but the selected language in select option doesnt change, why is that?
